# R comparison.cloud wordcloud error when empty corpus

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm using comparison.cloud() package over dynamically served data, which works fine. Then it often occurs that some corpus' element (document) is empty. This makes comparison.cloud return an error.

So far I've made a loop that does not include empty subsets:

```
quests <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3")
wordslist <- list()
rmlist <- numeric()
count <- 1

for (quest in quests) {
  wordslist[[quest]] <- subset(df$element, df$question == quest)
  if (length(wordslist[[quest]]) == 0) {
    rmlist <- c(rmlist, count)
    wordslist[quest] <- NULL
  }
  count <- 1 + count
  }
```

Then later on after having built the corpus I use the counter to remove the colnames :

```
tra$question <- tra$question[c(1,2,3)]
if (length(rmlist) != 0) {tra$question <- tra$question[-rmlist]}
```

So this works but I wanted to ask if it can somehow be improved, especially if there is any parameter I can feed to comparison cloud to help with this purpose. Also, is this behaviour a bug in comparison cloud ?

The results in my script are that if a question has no answers, this question won't be shown in the wordcloud. It would be much more preferable to have an empty question (the question title with its empty part of the wordcloud) than to have to remove it. By the way I tried sucessively to add :

- An `"empty_Qn"` character, result : it is at the center, ugly, big,
  draws all the attention
- The repetition of `"empty_Qn"` but the repetition is cleaned out by
  tm() and we again have the ugly output from above
- An empty string `""` or `" "` but here again it was stripped out, and
  I again had this error in comparison cloud due to an empty corpus
  part.

EDIT : whole script

```
## Elements per question wordcloud

library(wordcloud)
library(tm)

load(file="mygroupAnswers.Rda")

df <- df[df$group == groupname,]
df <- droplevels(df)

# Stop if no data
if(length(df$elements)==0) q(save="no")

quests <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3")
wordslist <- list()
rmlist <- numeric()
count <- 1

for (quest in quests) {
  wordslist[[quest]] <- subset(df$element, df$question == quest)
  if (length(wordslist[[quest]]) == 0) {
    rmlist <- c(rmlist, count)
    wordslist[quest] <- NULL
  }
  count <- 1 + count
  }

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(wordslist), readerControl = list(language = lang)) # Live Web version
#corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(wordALL), readerControl = list(language = "fr")) # RStudio version
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))

spStopWords <- c(stopwords(tra2), "l'", "j'", "d'", "c'", "qu'", "quand", "avoir", "être", "etre", "quelqu'un", "plus", "tant", "bien", "mal") # Live Web version
spStopWords <- c(stopwords("french"), "l'", "j'", "d'", "c'", "qu'", "quand", "avoir", "être", "etre", "quelqu'un", "plus", "tant", "bien", "mal") # RStudio version
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, spStopWords)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
tra$question <- tra$question[c(1,2,3)]
if (length(rmlist) != 0) {tra$question <- tra$question[-rmlist]}
colnames(tdm) <- tra$question

comparison.cloud(tdm, max.words=800, scale=c(6,1), title.size=1.2)
```

Comment: I don't see any call to `comparison.cloud`, which does work or does not work here (?).

Comment: You're right. I put the whole script so you can see the global logic and the comparison.cloud call. And changed it for a simpler version, while keeping the same logic.